# Symfony validate object on condition

Tags: symfony, validation

I would like to validate my `AddressDto` object only if `$hasAddress` is true. Is it possible somehow?

```
final class UserDto
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    public $hasAddress;

    /**
     * @var AddressDto
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    public $address;
}
```

```
final class AddressDto
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $postalCode;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $city;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $street;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $houseNumber;
}
```

I tried callback validation, which works, but I can't attach the errors to the fields, only to the parent form.

```
final class UserDto
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    public $hasAddress;

    /**
     * @var AddressDto
     */
    public $address;

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback()
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload): void
    {
        if ($this->hasAddress) {
            $errors = $context->getValidator()->validate($this->address, new Assert\Valid());

            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $context->buildViolation($error->getMessage())
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the validator documentation and you just need to add "atPath" to the context, which lets you specify the field you validate. Here is a link to the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html.

So the code should be:

```
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload): void
{
    if ($this->hasAddress) {
        $errors = $context->getValidator()->validate($this->address, new Assert\Valid());

        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $context->buildViolation($error->getMessage())
                ->atPath('address')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```